# How do I handle a HTML button click in Java, instead of Javascript, on Android?

Tags: java, android, html

I'm developing an *Android* application using *HTML* design. This design contains a `Form` and `Text Field` and a *submit* `Button`.

#### HTML Code:

```
<form name="form1" onSubmit="return showInfo()" >
  First name:<input type="text" id="fname"  autofocus placeholder="First name"/>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submitB"/>
</form>
```

#### Android Code:

```
WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.WebView1);
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/web/index.html");
```

The `HTML` design works well in the android UI, and this `HTML` file is connected to a separate `Javascript` file to handle the `onsubmit` event. For example, when the user presses on the submit button it calls a function in javascript file. All of this works great.

**My question is:** how I can reference this *submit button* in `Java` code? That is, I want this *submit button* in the `HTML` to be referenced in `Java` code when it is clicked on. I don't want to call the `javascript` function; I want, for example, to show a `Toast` message.

To illustrate :

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" id="submitB"/>
Button x = (button) findViewById(R.id.submitB) // I know this cant be happen but I want like this idea
```

I hope you got my Idea...

Comment: Is it required to use HTML and JavaScript? Why are you doing it like this instead of using simple android xml layouts?

Comment: I know it could be done by using simple xml layout,, but I'm doing that for a purpose

Answer (score 4):

You need to use [JavascriptInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29). To do this, first add your `Java` button and add it to the `WebView`:

```
Button submitB = (button) findViewById(R.id.submitB);
submitB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "HTML Button Clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
webView.addJavascriptInterface(submitB, "submitB");
```

Now you need to include the button statement in your `HTML` document, and specify the `onClick` attribute to perform the click on the `Java` button:

```
<button type="button" onclick="submitB.performClick()">Submit</button>
```

Now when you click the `HTML` button, it will show the toast message "HTML Button Clicked!"

Comment: perfect and simple